# Changing values in a dataframe depending on whether the subtraction of a neighbouring value results in a value > 1

Tags: r

This is my first time asking a question so apologies if I break any question-asking rules.

My problem is as follow:

I have a dataframe. For each value in this dataframe, I need to evaluate whether subtracting the neighbouring value in the next column results in an absolute value > 1, then change both values to NA if true, and do nothing otherwise.

Below is the code generating a dataframe equivalent to mine, and the code i have used so far to subtract pairs of columns from eachother.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#generate some random data 
data <- data.frame(replicate(80,sample(1:5,139,rep=TRUE)))

#subtract pairs of columns 
discrepancy <- data[,c(seq(9,80,2))]  - data[, c(seq(10, 80, 2))]
discrepancy <- abs(discrepancy)
```

Comment: In order to provide a reproducible example, you should always use set.seed() and paste it with your code, whenever you have functions with random outputs, such as sample()

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack.
You can write a function to replace NA with any value that is greater than one and then apply this to the discrepancy dataframe.

Write the function:

```
replaceNA <- function(x){
  ifelse(x > 1, NA, x)
}
```

Apply this to the dataframe

```
answer <- apply(discrepancy, 2, replaceNA)
```

Based on the comment, it sounds like you want to replace those original columns in `data` with `answer`. You can do this with:

```
data[,c(seq(9,80,2))]   <- answer
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps me with part of what i was struggling with. I didn't make it clear that what i need is to replace the values in the original dataframe, rather than in the discrepancy dataframe. Do you have an idea how to do this?